# Still No Response From style.css

Tags: html, css, web

I purchased an html template and am learning the ins and outs of editing it. I have figured out by now that CSS is used for style aspects like color and whatnot...The theme is currently an ugly yellow and I would like it to match our company logo colors (red and black). Is there a way to change the theme color in one go or am I going to have to edit individual components?

I have been attempting to edit the hover color in the navigation bar with no success. I will post the code and I would appreciate if someone could steer me in the right direction. Thanks so much, everyone.

```css
*/
.menu-bg {
 z-index: 999;
}
.menu-bg .basement-logo {
 padding-top: 5px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-default {
 background-color: inherit;
 border-color: inherit;
}
.navbar {
 border-radius: 0;
 min-height: auto;
 margin: 0;
 border: none;
 z-index: 9;
}
.navbar-collapse {
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
 color: #000;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 30px 13px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
 background-color: #DC143C !important;
 color: #000;
}
.menu-bg .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
 padding: 20px 10px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
 background-color: #DC143C !important;
 color: #000;
}
.navbar-collapse ul li a:hover{
  color:black;
  background-color:#DC143C;
}
/*
```

Comment: find and replace all? - find your hex colour and use an editor to replace all with your new hex colour.  Also make sure when you make a change, you do a hard refresh to force download of the css file again otherwise your browser will just use the cached version

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that was possible. How do I do a hard refresh?

Comment: You need to figure where is the color coming from? Use the [Developer tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to find the right element and then go find the element in your document and change the color. That would be a good start for you

Comment: https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/

Comment: Thanks, Pete. I see safari isn't listed on there- is this a bad browser for developing? I just looked at my webpage for the first time in chrome and its all kinds of fudged up :(

Answer (score 0):

1/ use this website to find every yellow or other colors in your css (enter a color) https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

2/ do a find/replace on your style.css and replace with your own color

3/ check if there is only one css file called in your html file . In this case, do find replace in each css file